# 'on click' on element with pointer events null (or alternative method)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I've embedded an iframe into my site, and I want to place an overlay, over the top of. My end goal is to have an overlay and text on top of the youtube video, that disappears when I play the video, and re-appears when I pause the video.

I want to be able to toggle a class of **video-playing** on the iframe wrapper, then show and hide the overlay based on if the parent has the class.

I've placed my overlay, on top of the iframe and added `pointer-events:none` to the overlay, so that when I hover over the overlay, the overlay itself is ignored and I can still click and play the iframe youtube video that sits underneath it.

My issue is that I need to register a function that runs when the iframe is played and paused, but I cant because

1. The overlay with `pointer-events:none` is stopping me from registering an onclick on the iframe.
2. I cant register an onclick on the overlay itself, because I need to be able to click the youtube video that sits underneath it, so `pointer-events:none` is required.

Is there any method of having the equivalent to `pointer-events:none` on the overlay, but still be able to register listeners and click events on the element that sits underneath it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe instead of trying to guess the playback state by whether or not the user clicked on the overlay (which may lead to errors, like clicking on volume or fullscreen button), you could use the actual official [youtube iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). It contains a lot of functionalities, and the one you are probably the most interested in is the [onStateChange event](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#onStateChange). By attaching to it, you can reliably check if the player is playing or paused (or in any other state like "buffering"). Based on the API documentation and your requirements I created a  [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rRzNXJ) that features an overlay that changes depending on the playback state.

PS. For some reason the embedded stackoverflow snippet has problems with embedding youtube iframes due to `Failed to execute ‘postMessage’ on ‘DOMWindow’` errors, but I'm posting the code below nevertheless, for completeness sake. For a working demo please see the codepen linked above.

```js
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
        events: {
'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

let overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
      overlay.classList.remove("paused");
      overlay.classList.add("playing");
    }
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
      overlay.classList.add("paused");
      overlay.classList.remove("playing");
    }
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  pointer-events:none;
}
.playing:before {
  position: absolute;
  content:"";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.3;
  background-color: green;
}
.playing:after{
  content: "playing";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  text-shadow: #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px,
             #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px;
}

.paused:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.3;
  background-color: orange;
}

.paused:after{
  content: "paused";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  text-shadow: #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px,
             #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px,   #000 0px 0px 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="player"></div>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

### Update

In case the iframe is added from CMS, you can still use the youtube API methods and attach it to an existing iframe element, like show in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OqjPOW). Basically, you provide just the events definition to the YT.Player constructor (as opposed to providing the whole videoID, height, width etc. parameter list):

```
player = new YT.Player('player', {
    events: {
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
});
```

Comment: I was thinking of this, but the way my site works currently, the user can simply paste an iframe in the CMS, so i'm trying to figure out a method that works with a youtube embed iframe!

Comment: It is possible to attach the youtube player API to an existing iframe, see the update to the answer.

Comment: Brilliant, thats a better solutions for me. Thanks!